# How should I calculate this expression?

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, circles

$\frac{\arccos\left(1\ - \frac{3}{2r^2}\right)}{2\pi}\cdot\pi r^2=\left(r^2-\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\ + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi}{12}$

Background: I'm calculating the radius of a circle with a chord of length $\sqrt{3}$ and the relative segment of area $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi}{12}$.
[Here is an image for it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLwJ0.jpg)

Notes: This is not a homework question, I'm just doing it to design an icon.

Thanks!

Comment: You have an equation in variable "r" - Are you looking for: (A) Algebraic solution for how to find "r" or (B) just the value of "r"?

Comment: @NoChance (A) is better, but if that's not possible, (B) is acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: Put the difference in  a spreadsheet formula that refers tp the value of $r$ elsewhere. Then experiment with $r$ until you're as close to $0$ as you need.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: If it works post an answer to your own question and accept it, or delete the question, so that it doesn't continue to attract attention.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry. I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, I am afraid that there is solution for $r$.

If $360$ stands for $2\pi$, this is a different story. Assuming it, you then look for the zero of function
$$f(r)=\frac{1}{2} r^2 \cos ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{3}{2 r^2}\right)-\left(\frac{3}{4} \left(r^2-\frac{3}{4}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{\pi }{12}\right)$$ which will not show any explicit solution.

Graphing, we can see that the solution is quite close to $\frac \pi 2$. So, to get an approximation, use Taylor series to get
$$f(r)=\frac{1}{48} \left(27-12 \sqrt{3}+4 \pi -9 \pi ^2+6 \pi ^2 \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi ^2-6}{\pi ^2}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{4} \left(r-\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right) \left(-3 \pi -2 \pi  \sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi ^2-3}}+2 \pi  \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi ^2-6}{\pi ^2}\right)\right)+O\left(\left(r-\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)^2\right)$$ and ignoring the higher order terms this will give (as an *approximation*)=
$$r=\frac \pi 2+\frac{27-12 \sqrt{3}+4 \pi -9 \pi ^2+6 \pi ^2 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi ^2-6}{\pi
   ^2}\right)}{12 \pi  \left(3+2 \sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi ^2-3}}-2 \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi ^2-6}{\pi ^2}\right)\right)}\approx 1.55899$$

If you need more accuracy, just use Newton method to obtain the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & r_n \\
 0 & 1.57079632679 \\
 1 & 1.55899274762 \\
 2 & 1.55893121417 \\
 3 & 1.55893121250
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

A more efficient way would be to let $r=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2 (1-x)} }$ which makes the function to be
$$g(x)=a + b x - \cos^{-1}(x)$$ where
$$a=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{\pi
   }{9}\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\pi }{9}$$ Function $g(x)$ really looks like a straight line.

Expanded as a Taylor series
$$g(x)=\left(a-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+(b+1) x+\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ which has one real root. Solving for it leads to $x=0.38320763$ to which corresponds $r=1.5594668$ which is not bad.

Being lazy, using Newton method with $x_0=0$ would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.0000000000 \\
 1 & 0.3893709937 \\
 2 & 0.3827904140 \\
 3 & 0.3827837464
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Very well put answer

Comment: Thanks! I meant $2\pi$. It was a typo.